# deleteAllMessagesOnStartup when using ActiveMQ in a network connected grid

Tags: activemq-classic

In a grid of 3 ActiveMQ 5.8 brokers connected via network connections how does the usage of `deleteAllMessagesOnStartup=true` impact the other members of the grid when one broker restarts?

Answer (score 1):

Using `deleteAllMessagesOnStartup=true` should *only* impact the broker on which it is used.